# http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard, extra '#' in url Angular 5

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having this issue with an Angular 5 project. All URL using localhost or even when hosted, a '#' is followed after the domain name. Can't find a reason for this.

app-routing.module.ts
There are children routes for other components

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'new-vendor-registration', component: NewVendorComponent},
  { path: 'new-vendor-card-add', component: NewVendorCardComponent },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: '', component: DashboardLayoutComponent, data: { title: '' }, children: DASHBOARD_ROUTES },
  { path: '', component: DashboardLayoutComponent, data: { title: '' }, children: USER_ROUTES, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: DashboardLayoutComponent, data: { title: '' }, children: OFFER_ROUTES, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: DashboardLayoutComponent, data: { title: '' }, children: PROMOTION_ROUTES, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
  // { path: '', component: TwoColumnsLayoutComponent, data: { title: '' }, children: TWO_COLUMN_ROUTES, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TwoColumnsLayoutComponent,
        DashboardLayoutComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        NewVendorComponent,
        NewVendorCardComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NgxDatatableModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        MyDatePickerModule,
        TextMaskModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
        AuthService,
        AuthGuard,
        VendorService,
        SalesrepService,
        PaymentService,
        SubscriptionService,
        OfferService,
        PromotionService,
        WeatherService,
        Broadcaster
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy show your app.module.ts

Comment: Can you show your `navbar` html code? I guess in your `anchor` tag `href="#"` is creating problem. Change it to "javascript:void(0)"

Comment: In index.html verify your base path, it should be something like <base href="/"> without the hash.

Comment: I updated post with app.module.ts @ngmodule. Base href set to "/". Still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the reason you are seeing the hash

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Read more about it here:

[HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy)

You most likely want this:

[PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy)

As per the [Description](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy#description)

> If you're using PathLocationStrategy, you must provide a APP_BASE_HREF
>   or add a base element to the document. This URL prefix that will be
>   preserved when generating and recognizing URLs.
>
> For instance, if you provide an APP_BASE_HREF of '/my/app' and call
>   location.go('/foo'), the browser's URL will become
>   example.com/my/app/foo.
>
> Similarly, if you add  to the document and call
>   location.go('/foo'), the browser's URL will become
>   example.com/my/app/foo.

Comment: I think this was added because of an issue when hosting the app. If I completely remove this it still can be hosted right ?

Comment: Usually removing the '#' interferes with how the routing will work with the server, hence adding the # works better for angular apps (or other frameworks for that matter). You can still get it to work without it, but it requires more setup

Comment: Thanks Ric for quick reply