# How to host an Angular-CLI project on GoDaddy?

Tags: angular, build, routes, angular-cli, web-hosting

I rebuilt a small business website for my family using the `angular-cli`, it's all frontend code with no server. I am running into an issue hosting the site on `GoDaddy`. I was able to get the initial landing page in the `index.html` to display on the main url, but none of the routing is working correctly. Every page displays a `404`. It was working fine locally.

I'm assuming this is a build issue, but I guess it could be an entirely different problem and I need a new approach.

My build steps:

- `ng build --prod`
- copy files in `/dist over to public_html` through an `ftp`

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I can provide any necessary files, I just wasn't even sure where to start.

**SOLUTION**

I had not implemented the `HashLocationStrategy` in my router. After doing so everything worked as expected.

Comment: What's your `base href` in your index.html look like?

Comment: @ChrisW. When you say `base href`, what exactly are you referring to? The redirectTo default is /home.

Comment: Take a look at this answer I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846422/http-localhost4200-dashboard-extra-in-url-angular-5/51846582#51846582 are you using HashLocation Strategy or Path?

Comment: @WilliamWheatonHolt It sounds like just a common [relative path issue](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#base-tag) like Ric is eluding to.

Comment: @Ric I am using Path I believe, as I have not implemented HashLocation. What do you recommend for my use case?

Comment: Exactly, try using hashlocation and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @Ric That worked like a charm. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your input as well!

Comment: @WilliamWheatonHolt You might also write your solution as answer to your question.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I had not implemented the HashLocationStrategy in my router. After doing so everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using #Angular9. I successfully uploaded the zipped dist folder to a subdomain on the Godaddy shared hosting. Without implementing the HashLocationStrategy, I just set the base tag in index.html as followed and it worked as expected.

```
 <!doctype HTML>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MyApp</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
```

This means #Angular9 app work for both PathLocationStrategy and HashLocationStrateg
but for Single page application HashLocationStrategy is better. For Angular Universal PathLocationStrategy should be used.